# Trying to delete from the grid under certain condition

Tags: java, vaadin8

```
private void delete() {
        
    if(customer.getStatus() == status.toString("Not Contacted")) {
        service.delete(customer);
        myUI.updateList();
        setVisible(false);
        
    }else {
        Notification.show("you cannot delete this");
    }
```

The error I get says "The method toString() in the type object is not applicable for the arguments (string)"

What I want to do is to let the delete function work only if the status is NotContacted.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```
 if(customer.getStatus() == status.toString().equals("Not Contacted")) {...}
```

Though you should want to give status a proper type to make a type-safe comparison. I suggest looking up on Enums (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) so that your code becomes something like

```
   if(customer.getStatus() == Status.NOT_CONTACTED)) {...}
```

Comment: I did it like this and scoped to the Enum for value i want and it worked.
             
`private void delete() {      
  if(customer.getStatus() == CustomerStatus.NotContacted) {
   service.delete(customer);
  
   myUI.updateList();

      setVisible(false);
      
      Notification.show("Customer susccefully deleted");
  }else {
   Notification.show("you cannot delete this");
  }
 }`